# "no such table" exception

Tags: python, django, sqlite, migrate, makemigrations

In Django I added models into `models.py`. After `manage.py makemigrations`, `manage.py migrate` raised this exception:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_test_usertranslatorprofile

I removed all old migrations and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again which seemed to work. It didn't help because when I click `User customer profiles` of `User translator profiles` it raises exception:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth_test/usertranslatorprofile/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'auth_test')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  618.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1550.                 self.list_max_show_all, self.list_editable, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in __init__
  82.         self.get_results(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py" in get_results
  177.         result_count = paginator.count
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py" in _get_count
  72.                 self._count = self.object_list.count()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in count
  318.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_count
  466.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in get_aggregation
  447.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  98.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  318.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/auth_test/usertranslatorprofile/
Exception Value: no such table: auth_test_usertranslatorprofile
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price_per_sign = models.FloatField()

class UserTranslatorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    price_per_word = models.FloatField()

class UserCustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

admin.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Language
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
class FreelancerRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all().order_by('shortcut'))
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you try clearing your database and trying again? Your migration will try to create everything but some things already exist and will fail anyway.

Comment: Do you mean manage.py flush? Yes I did that but it does not helped. How can I clear the database?

Comment: Could you run this in sql shell? select * from django_migrations where app='auth_test'; and post the output?

Comment: @Paulo I've executed the query in SQLite browser. It returned just one row: id:11; app:auth_test; name:0001_initial; applied: 2015-12-29 21:06:08.101000

Comment: Can you post the auth_test.0001_initial migration in a gist?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095742/operationalerror-at-admin-account-profile-no-such-table-account-profile I tried all the actions until I dig deeper myself and did It`s work) [Picture, thet is is work here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krxXd.png)

Comment: Maybe using `python3 manage.py migrate --fake` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385757/python3-manage-py-migrate-gives-error-about-field-even-when-it-is-deleted-from-t

Comment: The answer by @bhskarc solved it for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I solved the same problem with these steps :

- Delete your database (`db.sqlite3` in my case) in your project directory
- Remove everything from `__pycache__` folder under your project subdirectory
- For the application you are trying to fix, go to the folder and clear `migrations` and `__pycache__` directories

When you are sure you have cleared all the above files, run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: reaching wits end: what if `manage makemigrations` is the thing throwing the "django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: ......" error?

Comment: I have the same problem after opening to > python manage.py shell and then typing > from model_name.models import model1,model2 and then after calling > model1.objects.all() I get the error -- django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: model1

Comment: This solution will "work", but it requires nuking your migrations folder, which will give you headaches in production, particularly at scale. If you've stumbled over this comment and you're only ever going to run your code on your home PC, you can dust yourself off and carry on using this answer. If your code is ever going to touch a production server and/or you're curious as to why this is a bad idea in production, check out [link](https://www.algotech.solutions/blog/python/django-migrations-and-how-to-manage-conflicts/) and then have a read of Terry Brown's solution.

Comment: @buzzzz I tried manage,py migrate --run-syncdb as a poster below suggested and it worked. I tried messing with funny FieldSets and broke it somehow. Could you comment on this?

Comment: For me switching to `mysql` from the `sqlite` helped. I was having similar issues. When I deleted the entire `db.sqlite3` file and removed all `__pycache__` files, and all the make migrations files, some of my tables were still missing. I figured that out using `sqlite` database browser.

For me, taking `mysql` to production was more convenient, so any changes I've been making are working very well using the above two lines.

Answer (score 87):

run below command. It solves me once this issue

manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771755/django-operationalerror-no-such-table/37799885#comment90348355_37799885

Comment: When I got this error then I check my own gist https://gist.github.com/AthifSaheer/96eaa10599a84169d8d7980900dce666, But today that not helped me. This command worked `manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`.

Comment: This solved my problem. I also noticed that I had to recreate super user using the command `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` in order to login to the admin panel again

Answer (score 39):

Another case wihch can generate the **no such table** error.  If your views.py or similar executes code that tries to access the DB when imported, i.e. importing views.py has side effects, then **starting from scratch won't work**.

This happens when your code was working with an existing DB, and now you're trying to start without a DB.  Just change views.py so it can be imported without side effects.  If you don't want to fix the design, do something like:

```
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
format_list = [('', '(all)')]
geom_type_list = [('', '(all)')]
try:
    format_list.extend([(i[0],i[0]) 
        for i in Format.objects.values_list('name')])
    geom_type_list.extend([(i[0],i[0]) 
        for i in Geom_type.objects.values_list('name')])
except OperationalError:
    pass  # happens when db doesn't exist yet, views.py should be
          # importable without this side effect
```

Comment: I think I have this issue, though where should the code snippet above be run? And what is Format and Geom_type? Looks like models but where do they reside? (I get "NameError: name 'Format' is not defined")

Comment: @MrJalapeno the code goes at the start of views.py.  Format and Geom_type were specific to my app. - I was trying to make a module level list of available Formats/Geom_Types, and that fails when the DB has yet to be created.  If you're doing something similar, wrapping in a try:/except: like that might help.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working though :) My views imported my forms in which a query was causing the problem. Worked if I commented it out until the database was up and running.

Comment: Could you post an example of what "views.py or similar executes code that tries to access the DB when imported" looks like? I'm unsure whether this is my case. Thanks!

Comment: After spending around 2 hours, reading and trying out countless things from SO, GitHub, whatever I could find.... . YOU SAVED ME.  As with @MrJalapeno in my forms.py I had used the values  for populating the choices of the Char field. I had to use your code in my models.py also because one Model's choice depends on another model's unique values amongst rows. THANKS A LOT !!!!

Comment: This saved me. I was running a async process that was sending alerts based on things in the database. Commented out that process in views.py, and BOOM migrations worked perfectly.

Comment: I had the same issue and this helped.

Answer (score 21):

To solve it I did this (on Ubuntu, you'll need to adapt the commands for Windows):

**1. Remove all the migration files**

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete

find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

**2. Delete db.sqlite3**

```
rm db.sqlite3
```

**3. Create and run the migrations:**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

**4. Sync the database:**

```
manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Bit of a pain as you need to delete your database, but fine for a test system.
Got all but the final step from this generally excellent resource: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: All answers point to just migrating, but key for me was deleting the db.sqlite3 in step 2!

Comment: this is the way

Comment: Deleting the DB is not a good solution at all.

Comment: `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete` is dangerous as it deletes `django.db.migrations.migration` content.

Answer (score 15):

Using Django, I had to perform:

`python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: Worked for me after after deleting the old migrations and rerunning the makemigrations , migrate failed.

Comment: @othnin If you have already removed old migrations, please clean your database and remigrate.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to terry_brown's answer, this is what cause my problems. I had a custom user model with ForeignKey to another model. And I set defaults to first object in the DB. It worked when I had the data in the database. But when I started from scratch, it didn't work because it was executed immediately when imported (so not even migration went through).

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    subscription_plan = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionPlan, default=SubscriptionPlan.objects.first().id)
```

I had to sacrifice that `default` (commenting it out).

UPDATE: 
A better solution would be to prepopulate your database with initial migration or fixtures.

Comment: Same problem here. In my case, I had a class that tried to access the DB in its constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this steps to get fixed this issue.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME zero
```

This will make your migration to fake. Now you can run the migrate script

```
python manage.py migrate APPNAME
```

OR

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Tables will be created and you solved your problem.. Cheers!!!

Comment: This worked for me, but slightly different: I did the fake migration to zero, and then migrated the app, and finally did an additional fake migration. migrate --fake APP zero migrate APP, migrate --fake

Answer (score 3):

I read the above Answers given by other teams.
Majorly were asking to delete SQLite(DB) and reset the "migrations" folder.

If you are working in a production environment then this will not be the right choice.

1. `python manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME zero`
2. `python manage.py migrate APPNAME`
3. `python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME`
4. `python manage.py migrate APPNAME`

These four steps are enough to solve this issue.

Comment: The first step didn't worked

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I removed all migrations and run this command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

It worked for me and the data was also safe (I didn't lose any)

Comment: The second line created non existed table, even though the corresponding class was defined. Worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening because of the database of Django , this is not user fault. Its easiest solution is create new **app with different name** .Then create same models and then run **python manage.py makemigrations** and then migrate. By doing this your error should be solved

Answer (score 2):

Maybe migrations Folder was not created:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: This saved the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While running any management command "django.contrib.admin" automatically attempts to discover and admin.py modules in installed apps.

If there is a code related to database, it runs automatically and tries to load data from database when it can not find data related table in database throw this Error.

To fix this error just change `"django.contrib.admin"` in `INSTALLED_APPS` to `"django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig"`, it will prevent "django.contrib.admin" from auto discovering and running admin modules.

> django.contrib.admin automatically performs auto discovery of admin modules in installed applications. To prevent it, change your INSTALLED_APPS to contain 'django.contrib.admin.apps.SimpleAdminConfig' instead of 'django.contrib.admin'.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#troubleshooting

Comment: None of the other answers except this address the issue when a code inside `admin.py` tries to look out for some values data and causes an error.
But this takes away the rights of `superuser` to even `view` the models from the `admin`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need views to makemigrations. Comment out all references to other apps from urls.py, clear db and old migrations, run makemigrations, and comment your urls.py back in. Worked for me.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. was abe to solve after like 4 hours of trouble shooting +1 for you mate

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
None of the above solutions worked for me.
It all probably started when I added a new model, had a few objects in the database and then I changed model's name. 
I needed to delete the whole model from my app and then run app's admin page. Then I restored the model by clicking ctrl + z in all files from which I deleted it and finally I was able to run makemigrations and migrate commands.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error. The steps I used to solve this issue is:

1. Make sure that there's `migrations` folder inside your app. If there isn't any, create the `migrations` folder inside the app folder, and then create `__init__.py` file inside the folder.
2. If the `migrations` folder is already there, then delete all the `migration files`.
3. Delete the database file which is by default `db.sqlite3`.
4. Run the command `python manage.py makemigrations`
5. `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe out of time but...I have same problem when I tried to "clone" Django 1.11 installation into other directory and then with initial try to manage makemigrations.

I solve the problem following way:

1. settup initial Django installation and creating main application by:

django-admin.py startproject app_name

2. initial migrations 
   manage makemigrations, manage migrate
3. Setup the superuser:

manage createsuperuser

4. copy all files and directories (Django applications) except the urls.py and settings.py in main directory
5. Added all apps into INSTALLED_APPS
6. manage makemigrations, manage migrate
7. Copied settings.py and urls.py from source Django application directory

Thats it no errors and all is working fine.

Petr

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has this problem and the accepted solution is not working, have a look at your db path, 
the db path should be absolute path,

`'NAME': '/pathto-db/default.db',`

[Link](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12890/)

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solution worked for you then add the `appname` along with the `makemigration` and `migrate` command.

```
 makemigration login
 migrate login
```

That might help you to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while creating a model.
I opened the db.sqlite3 file and created a table for the model using SQLite DB Browser. Then I created a migration and fake migrated it. Don't know what caused the issue but this workaround helped.

Answer (score 0):

would you delete a production bank?
I saw that many have the sqlite deleted, but if it is a production bank?

solution to delete data from django_migrations table less contenttypes

already in the table django_content_type you remotely app_label

inside the migrations folder deletes everything but **init**.py

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate --fake

that's how I solved the app duplication problems (I had two apps with the same name after installing a plugin) and django created the missing tables, among other things.

in my normally functional case

Answer (score 0):

With same error and without removing database:

- remove migrations
- remove `__pychache__`
- `python manage.py makemigrations --empty alias`
- `python manage.py makemigrations alias`
- `python manage.py migrate alias zero`
- remove again migrations
- remove again `__pycache__`
- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate alias zero`

Where alias is the app name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the DB and migrating now this will happens.

For eg if your error says no such table `table1` then

- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py table1 app1

*Here **table1** is the name of the table and **app1** is the Django app name where the table1 model exists.*

Answer (score 0):

I know this commonly solved by deleting de sqlite3 DB that is used in the development process.

Also, I know this question is currently solved, but I want to leave my case here as an alternative.

Sometimes while we are programming we change a lot of things in our models. When we run `python manage.py makemigrations` a file is created inside of our `app folder/migrations`. And when we run `python manage.py migrate` a record in the table django_migrations is created. this record contains 3 fields we must check in detail:

- ###### 1 - name (this is the file name created in the migrations app folder)
- ###### 2 - app (this is the name of our app. Also works like a namespace to prevent conflicts)
- ###### 3 - applied (this is the date-time when the migration was executed).

If you've modified your model previously, you should have several files inside migrations (amount accordingly with the times you've executed makemigrations on every change), in my case I wanted to erase these files just to have only one migration file.

The problem with this is that when makemigrations was run again it creates a file 0001_initial.py. If you remember the table ***django_migrations*** contains a log of this file, this is to prevent the execution of migrations that already have been done.

If this is your case, you would erase the records of your app migrations from this table.

Answer (score 0):

I did some alterations in my database and was facing the same issue. None of solutions worked for me so after spending hours i finally decided to delete the "db.sqlite3" file and runs the makemigrations and migrate commands. After it worked fine. But this solution is not a good one to use immediately, use it only when you are out of options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem with this and used the @adam post to resolve my issue. I just wanted to amend his post and say that, for me in windows 10 using git bash, I had to do all of this from the venv, and then after I removed the migration files and the DB I had to `pip uninstall django` and `pip install django` before making the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes up for me when I have a function/class/etc. somewhere that uses fields from the Database -- typically when using Django's Form classes.

Example:

```
brands = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[(b.name, b.id) for b in Brand.objects.all()],
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
```

Here I'm creating a `MultipleChoiceField` entry for a form using the `name` and `id` fields from all `brand` object entries in a database. i.e. loading all the options a user can select *in* the database *from* the database.

When the database is already present and the `app_brand` table is already present, there is no issue.

However, when creating migrations for this application initially, I get the Error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_brand
```

I don't have an elegant work-around, but what I usually do is the following:

```
# default brands
try:
    brands = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[(b.name, b.id) for b in Brand.objects.all()],
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
except Exception as e:
    brands = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
```

This allows the initial `python manage.py makemigrations` command to be issued w/o raising the exception. The obvious downside is that there are likely cases that would normally cause the application to fail that might now simply result in an unpopulated form field in a production environment.

**TL;DR** - It's an issue sometimes if an application has functions/etc. that access the database such as Forms and those database tables don't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, cannot make migrations in no present database etc.. disabling forms import in view works, Importing form code to view works too, but this is solution:

I added `model = super().__class__()` in each `init` function in model form class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        model = super().__class__()    # 'soft code' prevents operational error
        self.fields['name'].required = False
```

And also I need to modify checkbox list:

```
  # CATEG_CHOICES= Category.choices_objects.all()
  # CATEG_CHOICES=Category.objects.values_list('id','name')  # without ..
   
  choice_list = []
    try:
        choice_list.extend(Category.choices_objects.all())
        # choice_list.extend(Category.objects.values_list('id','name'))
    except OperationalError:
        pass  # happens when db doesn't exist yet
         
    CATEG_CHOICES=choice_list
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way to fix my error was commenting out *every* single file. This error might occur while a file thinks the database is not empty, or that it actually exists.

I just commented out the entire project, migrated, uncommented the models.py file, migrated again, uncommented the entire project. I have no idea why it worked.