# "no such column" after adding a field to the model

Tags: python, django

environment
DJANGO VERSION 1.9
Python 2.7.6

I added a field (scores) to a model class in models.py like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import urllib
import hashlib


class profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    use_gravatar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    **scores = models.IntegerField(default = 0)**
```

and I run the following commands to sync the database.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

But got this

```
OperationalError at /
no such column: account_profile.scores
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: account_profile.scores
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['c:\\FairyBBS',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\setuptools-5.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\urlobject-2.4.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages\\djangorestframework-0.4.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    星期四, 17 三月 2016 14:08:04 +0800
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fast fix.

First remove field `scores`, Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If any error happens

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Then add field `scores`.Then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "If any error happens"   // but there is no errors. and I've tried the else commands , but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you tried removing and adding fields as descripbed above ?

Comment: yes i remove it 
  
`λ python manage.py makemigrations account
Migrations for 'account':
  0004_remove_profile_scores.py:
    - Remove field scores from profile`
and I add it 

  
`C:\FairyBBS
λ python manage.py makemigrations account
Migrations for 'account':
  0005_profile_scores.py:
    - Add field scores to profile`

  
still
`OperationalError at /
no such column: account_profile.scores`

Comment: after several times of trying ...it works~ THANK YOU VERY MUCH  :)

Comment: This is a good fix. But any idea why it is not able to migrate normally?

Comment: This error literally had me scratching me head for 3 days. I even tried performing a normal migrate prior to trying this solution, and it did not work. Thank you so much for this post.

Comment: literally after searching for hours finally this fix

Answer (score 9):

Well the problem is **NOT** with your makemigrations command or models.py. It is because you have probably imported your class in the model (your database in this case) in on of your views.py files and the problem is with that. If you read the all of the error message then you can understand that easily.

**Just try commenting that importing part and run your <kbd>python.manage.py makemigrations</kbd> and <kbd>python manage.py migrate</kbd> commands then you can uncomment your <kbd>import</kbd> in your views.py file**

Hope this was useful for others as well

Answer (score 7):

**This can happen if you are referencing your model at the root level of your app**

This happened to me when I was updating the app ***mapping_master***. I was adding a new field like so:

```
class MappingMaster(models.Model):

    ...

    # New field that was being added
    statement = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATEMENT_CHOICES, default='PNL', blank=True, null=True)
```

Gave me the following stacktrace:

```
D:\Adwaith\codebase\unitapp>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
312, in execute
    django.setup()

....
....

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in impor
t_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\Adwaith\codebase\unitapp\trial_balance_entry\models.py", line 5, in <
module>
    from unitapp import docclass
  File "D:\Adwaith\codebase\unitapp\unitapp\docclass.py", line 139, in <module>
    sample_train_type(type_classifier)
  File "D:\Adwaith\codebase\unitapp\unitapp\docclass.py", line 6, in sample_trai
n_type
    for mapping in MappingMaster.objects.all():

....
....

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line
318, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: mapping_master_mappingmaster.statement
```

Turns out that my problem was in another file entirely. It was in the ***trial_balance_entry*** app:

```
...
# The important line is below
from unitapp import docclass


class TrialBalanceEntry(models.Model):
    ...
```

And inside docclass.py, I had:

```
import re, csv, os
from mapping_master.models import MappingMaster


def sample_train_type(cl):
    for mapping in MappingMaster.objects.all():
        cl.train(mapping.entry, mapping.type)


def sample_train_category(cl):
    for mapping in MappingMaster.objects.all():
        cl.train(mapping.entry, mapping.category)

...
```

Turns out that the MappingMaster model instances were being referenced at the root of the app (since I imported it at the start of the file in the models file in ***trial_balance_entry***.

I fixed that by moving the import to one of the inner methods of my **TrialBalanceEntry** model. This made sure I didn't have any hidden circular dependencies.

*P.S. From next time, please provide a stacktrace from the console so we can debug it more easily.*

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it short and precise, give that field a default value.

For example:

```
nickname = models.CharField(max_length=12, default=" ")
```

and not `default=True`

If that doesn't work delete the migrations in your app's migration folder except

```
__init__.py file and type both the commands again.
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate(again)
```

Answer (score 1):

All, that u need: download «DB Browser for SQLite» and:

1. Copy your ‘db.sqlite3’ to different Folder.
2. Delete your ‘db.sqlite3’.
3. Run ‘python3 manage.py make migrations’, then ‘python3 manage.py migrate’.
4. Open your new ‘db.sqlite3’ in «DB Browser for SQLite» and find table ‘account_profile’
5. Then do like 1st image. U should export ‘account-profile’ table to CSV file.
6. Delete your new ‘db.sqlite3’ and return you old ‘db.sqlite3’
7. Open your DB in «DB Browser for SQLite», then «File—>Import—>Tables from file CSV..» and choose ‘account_profile.csv’
8. Then U will see, that in this table u should change columns ‘field1’ to ‘id’ and ‘field2’ to ‘user_id’. I did it on 2nd and 3rd images.
9. Last, what should u do: Look at ‘id’ of your admin in the table ‘auth_user’ and change on this value in the ‘account_profile table’
10. Delete your Admin-Model in DB(auth_user table)

Yeah, 5-10 minutes to do it, but all is work)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: result]

Comment: Why are you posting the same answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception

Comment: How does this even answer OP's question?

Comment: I'm new here and don't know all rules, Amanda...
I thought that it will be easier to find a solution not in the heap of comments, but already in a full post

Comment: @m02ph3u5, Using these steps, I added a table manually that was not added using standard migration commands

Answer (score 0):

Those migration issues bother me too when i have to update my app with new columns, so i've made a small bash with some python to search for troublesome columns, remove them, migrate, re-add them and migrate again.

Here is the `resolve.sh` that calls python and migrations (has to be placed in the same folder as your `manage.py` file, like the `.py` files) :

```
python manage.py shell < check.py

read -p "Does it seem ok ? (y for ok/n for remigrate)" migrateok

if [ $migrateok = "n" ]
then
    python manage.py shell < rm_badcolumns.py

    python manage.py makemigrations
    sleep 1
    python manage.py migrate

    python manage.py shell < resume_badcolumns.py

    python manage.py makemigrations
    sleep 1
    python manage.py migrate

    echo It should work now..
else
    echo No changes were made..
fi
```

`check.py` checks if there are issues with some models in the database :

```
from <app>.models import *
import os, sys
from shutil import move
from django.db import connection

tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)

errorColumn = []
is_fine = "EVERYTHING LOOKS FINE!"
#looping through models to detect issues
for model in seen_models:
    try:
        print(model.objects.all())
    except:
        is_fine = "WARNING SOME MODELS ARE CORRUPTED"

print(is_fine)
```

This check will tell the user if some models are not sync with your database.

If the user chooses to "re-migrate", it calls `rm_badcolumns.py` :

```
from <app>.models import *
import os, sys
from shutil import move
from django.db import connection


tables = connection.introspection.table_names()
seen_models = connection.introspection.installed_models(tables)

errorColumn = []

for model in seen_models:
    try:
        model.objects.all()
    except:
        errorColumn.append(str(sys.exc_info()[1])[30::]+' =')
        #this weird expression just get the column that causes trouble
        #you may have to adapt indexes depending on error output in exc_info

os.chdir('./<app>/')

#removing columns from models.py based on the error pattern
def replace(pattern, subst):
    with open('models_sub.py','w') as fout:
        with open('models.py','r') as models:
            for line in models:
                fout.write(line.replace(pattern, subst))

    os.remove('models.py')
    move('models_sub.py','models.py')

#applying this func to each error, and commenting out columns with an error mark to catch them back later
for errorStr in errorColumn:
    replace(errorStr, '#error_mark '+errorStr)

print 'Removing troublesome column for re-entering..'
```

Then `resolve.sh` will start another migration.
We uncomment the troublesome columns with `resume_badcolumns.py` to get them migrated again :

```
from <app>.models import *
import os, sys
from shutil import move
from django.db import connection


os.chdir('./<app>/')

#same search and replace func but returning True if sthg was replaced, and False otherwise
def replace(pattern, subst):
    a = False
    with open('models_sub.py','w') as fout:
        with open('models.py','r') as models:
            for line in models:
                fout.write(line.replace(pattern, subst))
                if pattern in line:
                    a = True
    os.remove('models.py')
    move('models_sub.py','models.py')

    return a

a = True
#while error_marks are replaced, we go on looping
while a:
    a = replace('#error_mark ', '')

print 'Re-adding troublesome columns..'
```

We make a final migration and everything should be fine.

This is a kind of heavy and dirty artillery for a small problem but i wanted it to be automatized.
A few points may need some rework, such as the way i identify which column is not synced, and i'd appreciate comments about this.

Answer (score 0):

Easyes Solution:
RENAME the field
makemigrations
migrate
RENAME back
makemigrations
migrate