# Django cannot access model in admin site

Tags: django, python-3.x

I was trying to adjust a DateField in one of my models to also show the time (DateTimeField). I ended up also making timezone adjustments. After all I decided to not use the time and deleted the additional code and set the field back to DateField. Migrations are made and migrated. Now when trying to access an object from the model either via the page or admin page I receive the error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'24 22:00:00'
```

So after trying a few things I just wanted to delete the objects in the model using the admin page. This also resulted in the above error.

It seems every page relying on an object from that model throws the error.

Is there a way to force delete objects?
Can you recommend any other clean up methods?

The model is defined as:

```
class PieceInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular Piece across whole system')
    piece = models.ForeignKey('Piece', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    version = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_claimed = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    claimant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_sent_to_claimant = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    PIECE_STATUS = (
        ('n', 'Not Claimable'),
        ('a', 'Available'),
        ('r', 'Reserved'),
        ('c', 'Claimed'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=PIECE_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='a',
        help_text='Piece Availability',
    )

    @property
    def claimed_overdue(self):
        days_till_claimed_overdue = 7
        if self.date_claimed and date.today() > self.date_claimed + timedelta(days=days_till_claimed_overdue):
            return True
        return False

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_claimed']
        permissions = (('can_mark_sent_to_claimant', 'Set Piece Instance as sent to claimant'),) 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} ({self.piece.title})'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my project is not big I decided to drop the whole database and set it up again from scratch.
I used the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception/36453000) question

Note that you also have to set up all users again (including the superuser)