# Unable save table after making changes in the model.py file

Tags: python, django, django-excel

I am new to django any help would be much appreciated.

I have installed the django-excel tutorial app and made changes to its model.py file.

I have done the following steps :

1) python manage.py makemigrations polls

Output : Migrations for 'polls':
  polls\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model hpcl

2) python manage.py migrate polls

output : Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: polls
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

```
Model.py file 

from django.db import models


    class hpcl(models.Model):
        plannedPLT = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        consumption = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        required_PLT = models.CharField(max_length=200)


        def __str__(self):
            return self.pub_date


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/import/

Django Version: 2.2.1
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: polls_hpcl) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\Documents\Notes\Feedstock\Django-excelV2\django-excel-master\polls\views.py" in import_data
  53.                     ['plannedPLT', 'pub_date', 'consumption', 'required_PLT']

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\Documents\Notes\Feedstock\Django-excelV2\django-excel-master\django_excel\__init__.py" in save_book_to_database
  63.         pe.save_book_as(**params)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\core.py" in save_book_as
  112.     return sources.save_book(book, **dest_keywords)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py" in save_book
  56.     return _save_any(a_source, book)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\internal\core.py" in _save_any
  60.     a_source.write_data(instance)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\sources\db_sources.py" in write_data
  111.             **self._keywords

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\plugins\renderers\django.py" in render_book_to_stream
  75.             **keywords

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py" in save_data
  129.         **keywords

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py" in store_data
  146.         writer.write(data)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\book.py" in write
  221.                 sheet_writer.close()

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\database\importers\django.py" in close
  58.                 an_object.save()

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\dhaval1.desai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /polls/import/
Exception Value: no such table: polls_hpcl
```

Comment: do `python manage.py migrate` instead of `python manage.py migrate polls`

Comment: I tried it getting the same errors.Could you suggest something else that I could do ?

Comment: remove the migration files and try again

Comment: Getting the same error, what could be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by following the steps mentioned in the answer : 
(view for a detailed explanation)
[Django - no such table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception/36453000)

You need to follow the following simple steps to resolve the above issue :

1)Delete your database (db.sqlite3 in my case) in your project directory

2)Remove everything from **pycache** folder under your project subdirectory

3)For the application you are trying to fix, go to the folder and clear migrations and **pycache** directories

When you are sure you have cleared all the above files, run:

python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate