# Django 2.2 - django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table

Tags: python, django, sqlite, migration, makemigrations

I am pulling my hair out. I just can't get migrations to work anymore. Every time I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` or `python3 manage.py makemigrations app_name` I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: catalog_fault

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/peter/Documents/21q/locallibrary/urls.py", line 60, in <module>
    loader.load_db()
  File "/home/peter/Documents/21q/catalog/loader.py", line 106, in load_db
    add_game(*game, batch=True)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/21q/catalog/models.py", line 315, in add_game
    fault = add_fault(fault_name, batch=batch)
  File "/home/peter/Documents/21q/catalog/models.py", line 327, in add_fault
    fault = Fault.objects.get(fault__icontains = fault_name)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1133, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/peter/.virtualenvs/21q_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: catalog_fault
```

I have read lots of Q&As on Stackoverflow and other sites but just can't solve the problem.

I've tried following the steps in the following accepted answer but it makes no difference: [Django - no such table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception)

I've been trying to fix this problem for hours and I'm just not getting anywhere.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: From the stack link, you have tried please delete database and migrations except  `__init__.py` file inside migration folder then again migrate I think that should work!

Comment: Thanks @MehaParekh. I've literally just solved it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having code in on module level that executed a query further down the stack:

```
fault = Fault.objects.get(fault__icontains = fault_name)
```

On module level this code will be executed when the module is analyzed by `makemigrations` and the resulting query will fail since the database table is not created yet.

As a solution you will have to place that code at a location where it will not be executed on import or you have to handle the exception raised.

Comment: Thanks @Klaus that's very helpful. If I want to automatically load data into the db when starting up the server (i.e. runserver), what's the best approach for that? I clearly need to do it after the models have been loaded / db tables have been set up. Thanks

Comment: Hi, what `place that code at a location where it will not be executed on import` means in this case? any practical example please?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, after hours of getting nowhere, I've literally just solved it!

Turns out I was trying to load data into the sqlite database in `urls.py` before the database was ready.

`makemigrations` triggered the `loader.load_db()` call before `migrate` was performed. Once I commented out `loader.load_db()` the migrations worked perfectly! :)

So in summary, make sure you're not trying to load any data into the database until after `makemigrations` and `migrate` have been performed.

Comment: where i can find the loader.load_db() ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem when I was trying to change function-based views to class-based views. I tried to assign class variables by calling database query, so that it was trying to make database calls before creating actual tables, after removing this assignment *`makemigrations`* worked perfectly.

Here is how my code example, when I was catching this error

```
class SampleView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    sample_variable = SampleModel.objects.get(active=True)
```

The way I resolved this problem

```
class SampleView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    sample_variable = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        self.sample_variable = SampleModel.objects.get(active=True)
        return super(SampleView, self).get_object(queryset)
```

If you're facing such an error, check out your views, probably the same mistake caused the error in your code.

In my case, I moved database query and variable assignment to overridden get method and left the variable with *None* value on initialization

P.S i override *`get_object`* for this example, but you can move assignment of the variable to some distinct function

Comment: what do you mean `after removing this assignment?`. Probably you are referring to what you said then in the following paragraph `In my case, I moved database query and variable assignment to overridden get method and left the variable with None value on initialization`. can you please add some code examples?

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo Apologies, for being inexplicit, added additional code example of the possible solution to this problem