# Why is my else statement not working in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code:

views.py

```
@api_view(['DELETE'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def selected_job_delete(request,pk=None):
    if pk != None:
        job=Job.objects.get(pk=pk)
        jobdetail = Job_detail.objects.get(job=pk)
        jobtrack = Job_track.objects.get(job = pk)
       
        jr = Job_removed()
        jdr = Job_detail_removed()
        jtr = Job_track_removed()

        jr.jobname = job.jobname    
        jr.owner = job.owner    
        jr.enabled = job.enabled    
        jr.start_date = job.start_date    
        jr.start_time = job.start_time    
        jr.date_added = job.date_added    
        jr.version = job.version
        jr.save()

        jdr.job = jr
        jdr.json = jobdetail.json
        jdr.save()

        jtr.job=jr
        jtr.jobdetail= jdr
        jtr.save()

        operation = job.delete()
        
        data = {}
        if operation:
            data["Success"] = "Successfully deleted"
        else:
            data["Failure"] = "Unsuccessful"
        return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
path('api/jobs/<int:pk>/delete', views.selected_job_delete),
```

Lets say my database in `Job` have the **only** following id of `40`. I want to delete it so i key the url of `api/jobs/40/delete` and the deletion will happen, followed by the task in the function. The output result in my postman will show it is `successfully deleted` . But if I key the url of `api/jobs/41/delete`, the id of `41` does not exist in my database, it does not run my else statement to show `unsuccessful` .

Instead it shows me

[image]

How can I make it to show `unsuccessful` instead of the whole chunk of the error that it does not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must catch the exception `Job.DoesNotExist`:

```
@api_view(['DELETE'])
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def selected_job_delete(request, pk=None):
    if pk != None:
        try:
            job=Job.objects.get(pk=pk)
            jobdetail = Job_detail.objects.get(job=pk)
            jobtrack = Job_track.objects.get(job = pk)
            jr = Job_removed()
            jdr = Job_detail_removed()
            jtr = Job_track_removed()

            jr.jobname = job.jobname    
            jr.owner = job.owner    
            jr.enabled = job.enabled    
            jr.start_date = job.start_date    
            jr.start_time = job.start_time    
            jr.date_added = job.date_added    
            jr.version = job.version
            jr.save()

            jdr.job = jr
            jdr.json = jobdetail.json
            jdr.save()

            jtr.job=jr
            jtr.jobdetail= jdr
            jtr.save()

            operation = job.delete()
       
            if operation:
               return Response({"Success": "Successfully deleted"})
        except Job.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return Response({"Failure": "Unsuccessful"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer! May I ask how do I catch the error for no such table?

Comment: @L.Calvin No problem for the answer. For no such table exception you should check your migrations (did you run the command `python manage.py makemigrations` and the command `python manage.py migrate`?), because it means that you have database inconsistency. Take a look also at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception) if you don' t solve the issue

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this:

```
try:
    job.delete()
except:
    data["Failure"] = "Unsuccessful"
    return Response(data)
```

**update**

```
try:
   job=Job.objects.get(pk=pk)
except: Job.DoesNotExist:
   data["Failure"] = "Unsuccessful"
   return data
```