# when migrating django codes to the database Errno 2 No such file

Tags: django, database, makemigrations

I am connecting my database with Django codes so when I use
python manage.py makemigrations I get the error as no such file

py manage.py makemigrations
C:\Users\selwy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\selwy\projects\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\selwy\projects>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the entire output after you run `python manage.py makemigrations`. Feel free to edit sensitive information such as your name, but we need more of the output than you provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with these steps :

1. Delete your database (db.sqlite3 in my case) in your project directory.
2. Remove everything from **pycache** folder under your project subdirectory.
3. For the application you are trying to fix, go to the folder and clear migrations and **pycache** directories

When you are sure you have cleared all the above files, run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

For further references,visit:
[Django - no such table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception)