# Why is Django having trouble accessing my User table?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and web development in general. I am trying to test my app, recipe_book, using the admin page.

When try to login at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin, I get the following error:

> no such table: recipe_book_user

I have a model class named "User", defined below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

I then successfully made migrations and migrated the changes.

To resolve this issue, I've tried registering the User class in `admin.py`, with no success. I've also tried following the steps to reset the database in the following question:

[Django - no such table exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548768/django-no-such-table-exception)

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Does your user model appear in the migration files that you generate and migrate?

Comment: I looked at the database in sqlite3 and I don't see any tables for the models I created. Although I do see some called "auth_group" and so on. So I guess it did not migrate correctly. Do you know if there are other files I could check?

Comment: You can look at the actual migration files that Django creates in your app's `migrations` folder, they will be the same as the console, e.g. `0001_auto_blah_blah.py`

Comment: Hm I actually don't see a migrations folder! Just `__pycache__` and the templates folder I created.

Comment: Did you put your app name in your settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS` list?

Comment: I did, yes. Under `'django.contrib.staticfiles'`

Comment: Rather odd, try manually adding a `migrations` folder with an `__init__.py` file within and then re-run makemgirations and migrate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247107/discussion-between-spheroidic-and-0svoid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this - it turns out that my migrations weren't being created. I had been typing `python manage.py makemigrations` instead of `python manage.py [app_name]` in my initial migration. Problem solved!